# Sending mail through python by using SMTP

Tags: python, email

To reproduce my issue, here is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
email=EmailMessage()
email['from']='Pratik Mishra'
email['to']='pratikmishra79@gmail.com'
email['subject']='Hi there! congratulations you won $10,000'
email.set_content("i am a python master ")
with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('pratik.jgd17@gmail.com','password')# can't write password here
    smtp.send_message(email)
    print("hello this was a joke")
```

I am getting this output message from the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\prati\Documents>python email_sender.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_sender.py", line 11, in <module>
    smtp.login('pratik.jgd17@gmail.com','password')
  File "C:\Users\prati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\prati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\prati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a23sm994647pfo.145 - gsmtp')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this means one of 3 things. 1, your username and password aren't correct, 2, you haven't enabled allow less secure apps on your google account, or 3, you have 2-Step Verification on. You can enable less secure apps by following these steps:

- [Click Here to Access Less Secure Apps Settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
- Next to “Allow less secure apps: OFF,” select the toggle switch to turn ON.

If you want to use it with 2-Step Verification, you will need to generate a personal access token for your google account and use that for your password, [here](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)